# how to fix: boolean array for random lottery number program. "can't convert int to boolean"

Tags: java, arrays, random, int, boolean

I need to make a random lottery generator for class  with a boolean array.  at first i made it with an int array and it worked perfectly fine but when i changed the int array to a bool array i got an error that says "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean". I'm wondering how to fix my code so this will work.

```
    int highestNumber, numsInLottery, randomNum;
    //int[] lottery = new int[numsInLottery];

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Lottery Number Generator!");
    System.out.println("How many numbers are in your lottery?");
    numsInLottery = TextIO.getInt();
    System.out.println("What is the highest number in your lottery?");
    highestNumber = TextIO.getInt();

    boolean[] lottery = new boolean[numsInLottery];

    for(int i = 0; i < numsInLottery; i++)
    {
        randomNum = (int)(Math.random() * highestNumber);
        for(int x = 0; x < i; x++ )
        {

            /*if (lottery[x] == randomNum)
            {
            randomNum = (int)(Math.random() * highestNumber);
            x = -1;
            }*/
        }   
        lottery[i] = randomNum;
        System.out.print(lottery[i] + " ");
    }

        //System.out.print(lottery[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, for a start do you know what boolean stands for and what two values it can hold?

Comment: yes I know boolean can only hold true or false

Comment: Great! So what have you tried here with that? :-)

Comment: I've tried to convert the int to a boolean and I have tried lottery[x] = true or false. both did not work

Comment: That's OK, life is all about trying, but did we make some logic behind that try? I mean what do we expect to happen once we do all that?

Comment: As @MS90 mentioned,could you please provide us what is the logic here.What should be done, what should be an effect of what you've done. You mentioned that you used int before boolean so you stored randomly generated number into array when user provide the size for an array but what is the usage of boolean here? :) I believe you just tried to use some data types in this concrete example but as you probably know in this example,data types like boolean or String does not make sense at all if you want just store data in some structure. You can use numerical data types here I think :)

Answer (score 0):

you're assigning an int to your lottery[i] in the line

```
        lottery[i] = randomNum;
```

an alternative would be to keep the int array, or say

```
        lottery[i] = randomNum>(highestNumber/2);
```

so you have a boolean value instead of  your integer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your boolean array will have `true` and `false` values at random indices, you just need to check for the following condition:

```
for(int x = 0; x < i; x++ ){

    if(lottery[x]){
        randomNum = (int)(Math.random() * highestNumber);
        x = -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I check for that? Would I equal lottery[x] to true or false somewhere?

Comment: With boolean array, you can fill the array with `true` or `false`, let's say between 1 and 100. Now, when user enters a number, you can see whether the value present at that index is `true` and if yes, you can show a message saying user has won.